# Shredding XML in postgresql

Tags: xml, postgresql, plpgsql

In SQL Server 2005's T-SQL language I can shred XML value the following way:

```
SELECT
    t.c.value('./ID[1]', 'INT'),
    t.c.value('./Name[1]', 'VARCHAR(50)')
FROM @Xml.nodes('/Customer') AS t(c)
```

where @Xml is a xml value something like

```
'<Customer><ID>23</ID><Name>Google</Name></Customer>'
```

Can someone help me to achieve the same result in PostgreSQL (probably in PL/pgSQL)?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `xpath` function will return an array of nodes so you can extract multiple partners. Typically you would do something like:

```
SELECT (xpath('/Customer/ID/text()', node))[1]::text::int AS id,
  (xpath('/Customer/Name/text()', node))[1]::text AS name,
  (xpath('/Customer/Partners/ID/text()', node))::_text AS partners
FROM unnest(xpath('/Customers/Customer',
'<Customers><Customer><ID>23</ID><Name>Google</Name>
 <Partners><ID>120</ID><ID>243</ID><ID>245</ID></Partners>
</Customer>
<Customer><ID>24</ID><Name>HP</Name><Partners><ID>44</ID></Partners></Customer>
<Customer><ID>25</ID><Name>IBM</Name></Customer></Customers>'::xml
)) node
```

Where you use `unnest(xpath(...))` to break a big chunk of xml into row sized bites; and [`xpath()`](http://scottrbailey.wordpress.com/2009/06/19/xml-parsing-postgres/) to extract individual values. Extracting the first value from an XML array, casting to `text` and then casting to `int` (or `date`, `numeric` etc) is not really comfortable. I have some helper functions on my blog to make this easier, see [XML Parsing in Postgres](http://scottrbailey.wordpress.com/2009/06/19/xml-parsing-postgres/)

Answer (score 7):

Use [the xpath-function in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-xml.html) to proces the XML.

Edit: Example:

```
SELECT
    xpath('/Customer/ID[1]/text()', content),
    xpath('/Customer/Name[1]/text()', content),
    *
FROM
    (SELECT '<Customer><ID>23</ID><Name>Google</Name></Customer>'::xml AS content) AS sub;
```

Comment: Thank you, I've already checked this. What I'd like to see is some sample codes.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Just 2 more hints will be much appreciated. 1) What if ID is number? 2) What if the original xml has multiples partners <Partners><Partner/><Partner/></Partners>?