# Extracting XML element value from Postgres

Tags: postgresql, xpath, xml-parsing, xquery, plpgsql

Given:

```
CREATE TABLE xmltest(xtxt xml);
```

And:

```
INSERT INTO xmltest values ('<EMP><NAME>Mike</NAME><HIREDATE>12-FEB-96</HIREDATE></EMP><EMP><NAME>Bob</NAME><HIREDATE>13-AUG-97</HIREDATE></EMP><EMP><NAME>Paul</NAME><HIREDATE>17-JUN-94</HIREDATE></EMP><EMP><NAME>Jim</NAME><HIREDATE>01-JUN-94</HIREDATE></EMP>');
```

Using the base functionality of Postgres 9.2, how would I write a SELECT statement that returned only the employee names, 1 name per row in the result set? Or would I have to write a function in PL/PGSQL to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can extract fields of interest into an array using the `xpath` function, and then from there you can use the `unnest` builtin to split this array into multiple rows:

```
SELECT unnest(xpath('//name', xtxt))
FROM   xmltest;
```

(Slightly borrowed from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3650391/shredding-xml-in-postgresql))

Comment: Thanks, it's almost there. I have multiple employees in the row, and as written, this gags after the first one with "Extra content at the end of the document." So I have to work on it. Having said that, your code is clearer in demonstration than this demo in the docs http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/interactive/functions-xml.html#FUNCTIONS-XML-PROCESSING  ..also following the links in your reply lead to a helpful blog post http://scottrbailey.wordpress.com/2009/06/19/xml-parsing-postgres/

Comment: That may be because your original XML is invalid, there isn't a single root node. You have multiple <EMP /> objects, but nothing to wrap them, that's possibly causing the problem.